# jQuery fancybox gallery on website - img settings

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, fancybox

I have desktop version enforcement enabled on phones and when manually zooming in on the page and then the open photo is still in the same place, how to make it always visible in the center regardless of page zoom?

The website address is: https://xn--kt-pla.pl

[without approximation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2Dw8.jpg) (the photo is 100% visible)

[after a slight zoom page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzTzW.jpg)

[after high zoom page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fey6P.jpg) (When you zoom in and then open the photo, it is still in the same place, it is invisible)

Probably need to add some values ​​to one of these classes:
.fancybox-slide--image .fancybox-content
.fancybox-slide
.fancybox-image
.fancybox-slide img

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately i don't know, how you center the image or where these classes belong to. But you could add an eventlistener for the zoom (and optional for rotation of the phone), and then reposition your image (via a reference to the function that does the reposition = functionReference ;).

eventlistener example (jquery):

```
$(window).on('resize orientationchange', functionReference);
```

If that doesn't helps you, it would be better to add some relevant code pieces (not the whole files ;) to your question (at least css and js)...

Comment: Hey, do you know how to close an open gallery on phones? On computers, it is enough to click on the dimmed field outside the photo, and on the mobile version it does not work

Comment: It depends on the Code. Please post some relevant code pieces from your html, js & css as mentioned above...

Comment: It is not enough to enter the site https://xn--kt-pla.pl  ?, gallery uses fancybox so it's hard to copy it all

Comment: I tested your site on my pc and phone (mobile and desktop mode). When i changed the window size (smaller browser window or rotating the phone) the fancybox image was automatically centered. But i could in no case zoom in. Maybe that's because the only styling for the fancybox in your css file ist **position: sticky !important**. The documentation of fancybox says, that it is perfekt for pinch and zoom, but doesn't tell anything about it in the options (except disabling) or somewhere else. The same for closing it manually (e.g. closing by touch outside the fancybox).

Comment: I found the following phrase in the doc: **fancybox has been tested in following browsers/devices: ... Android 7.0 Tablet** -> thats the only Android device there. I tested it with my galaxy s4 ;)>  Maybe you should build your own lightbox or use a better documented library...